# How much concurrent read and write the namenode support?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Does anyone know hdfs concurrent read and write? How to calculate the number of concurrent read and write?

Comment: can you specify your question? did you mean the bytes readed/written in total? if so, one can have a look at the job statistics (click on the job in your webinterface). there are a lot of byte counter with information regarding read and write. e.g. Map input records, Map output records

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask : the throughput of file operating in HDFS,

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a lot of variables (hardware, number of nodes, workflow).

I suggest installing [Ganglia](http://ganglia.info/) to monitor your cluster and observe how it behaves.